# Are Ito bridges themselves Ito processes?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

> Let $X_t$ be an Ito diffusion process with initial condition $X_0 = x_0$. Let $T>0$ we a fixed deterministic time, and consider for $0 \leqslant t < T$ the process $Y_t = X_t| X_T = x_T$. Is this process an Ito process ? If so, how can one find its SDE ?

For Wiener process the answer is in affirmative:
$$
    \mathrm{d} Y_t = -\frac{Y_t}{T-t}\mathrm{d} t + \sigma \mathrm{d} W_t , \quad Y_0 = 0
$$
I suspect it might be the case in general (i.e. Ito bridge is an Ito process), at least for time-homogeneous Ito diffusions, using stochastic changes of time. I am hoping for a reference to a relevant books/articles.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at Section 1.1 of the following [paper](http://www.mat.ub.edu/~corcuera/EF.pdf) and for the case you are interested in (under some conditions) I think that Example 8 is giving a satisfying (theoretical) answer to your question.

Best regards

Comment: @ Sasha : you can also try to look at this article : http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/mathdoc/textes/PMA-649.pdf, best regards.

Comment: Both links are broke. Could you please update them? Thank you.

Comment: try here : http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/mathdoc/preprints/baudoin.Wed_Apr__4_17_30_17_CEST_2001.html

Comment: The link does not lead to the paper. This http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.194.4414&rep=rep1&type=pdf does.

Comment: google it you'll find it

Comment: You probably did not read the second sentence of my last comment.

Comment: None of the links worked for me. For future reference, the paper is [*Conditioned Stochastic Differential Equations: Theory and Applications* by Fabrice Baudoin](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/032a/302f623b5fe796e43c2f2a1ebb9d8b523337.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Under mild assumptions, a conditioned diffusion is still a diffusion. Indeed, the diffusion $dX = \mu(X) \, dt + \sigma(X) \, dW$ conditioned on the event $X_T=y_T$ follows the stochastic differential equation
$$dX = \Big( \mu(X) + \sigma^2(X) \, \frac{\partial_x h(t,x,y_T)}{h(t,x,y_T)} \Big)\, dt + \sigma(X) \, dW$$
where $h(t,x,y) \, dy = \mathbb{P}(X_T \in dy \,| X_t=x)$ is the density of $X_T$ conditioned on the event $X_t = x$. This is a Doob h-transform. More can be read [here](http://linbaba.wordpress.com/tag/doob/).